# Выход из рекурсии

Tags: javascript, рекурсия

Не могу выйти из рекурсии

```js
function consoleRec(sourse) {

  console.log(sourse.shift());
  consoleRec(sourse);

}
consoleRec(['я', 'умею', 'писать', 'рекурсивные', 'функции']);
```

Условие: 
Запрещено использовать циклы и методы для работы с массивами. Функция должна принимать два аргумента: массив и… что-то еще. Что именно - остается на ваше усмотрение.

Пример вызова:

```
consoleRec(['я', 'умею', 'писать', 'рекурсивные', 'функции'], ???);
```

Должна вывести на экран:

```
я
умею
писать
рекурсивные
функции
```

Comment: __запрещено использовать массивы но функция может принимать массивы__ логично

Comment: @Избытоксусликов, запрещено использовать **методы для работы с массивами**, а не сами массивы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Реализация рекурсивного алгоритма **всегда** должна содержать в себе:

- Рекуррентное отношение
  Это то, каким образом мы сводим решение задачи к решению задач **меньшего** размера.
- Крайние случаи
  Это то, что поможет нам вовремя остановиться, некие тривиальные случаи, которые можно решить на месте, не прибегая к разбиению задачи на подзадачи.

В своей реализации вы забыли про второе.

```js
function consoleRec(src) {
  if (src.length === 0) return; // крайний случай, пустой массив
  console.log(src.shift());     // действие текущей итерации
  consoleRec(src);              // рекурсивный вызов для уменьшенного массива
}
consoleRec(['я', 'умею', 'писать', 'рекурсивные', 'функции']);
```

---

Обращаясь к условию Вашей задачи

> Запрещено использовать циклы и методы для работы с массивами

мы не можем изменять исходный массив(или срезать его части), поэтому вторым параметром придётся передать текущий размер задачи:

```js
/* Передача размера задачи 
 */
function r1(src, taskSize) {
  if (taskSize === 0) return;
  r1(src, taskSize-1);
  console.log(src[taskSize-1]);
}

/* Передача индекса начала необработанной части массива 
 */
function r2(src, start) {
  if (start === src.length) return;
  console.log(src[start]);
  r2(src, start + 1);  
}


let list = ['я', 'умею', 'писать', 'рекурсивные', 'функции'];

r1(list, list.length);
r2(list, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Не могу выйти из рекурсии

Вот так можно это реализовать:

```js
function consoleRec(source, i) {
  // Условие для выхода
  if (source.length - 1 >= i) {
    // Печать
    console.log(source[i]);
    // Вызов рекурсии
    consoleRec(source, i + 1)
  }
}

consoleRec(['я', 'умею', 'писать', 'рекурсивные', 'функции'], 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let res = '';

function consoleRec(arr, indx = 0) {
  res += arr[indx] + '\r\n';
  indx++;
  if (indx < arr.length) {
    consoleRec(arr, indx);
  }
  return res;
}

    //Вызов 
    const arr = ['я', 'умею', 'писать', 'рекурсивные', 'функции'];
    console.log(consoleRec(arr, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
void function r(f, arr, i = 0) { f(arr[i]) || i++ < arr.length - 1 && r(f, arr, i) }(console.log, ['я', 'умею', 'писать', 'рекурсивные', 'функции'])
```

к стати, в условии задачи не сказано про рекурсию

```js
let f = (a, b) => b(('' + a).replace(/,/g, '\n'))
f(['я', 'умею', 'писать', 'рекурсивные', 'функции'], console.log)
```